# TSQL IF THEN WHERE something ELSE WHERE something else

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to transform this c# line into a SQL query:

```
from t in table where type == 0 ? t.colA=1 : t.ColB=1
```

I've tried something like

```
select * from table t where
BEGIN IF @type=0 THEN t.colA=1 END
BEGIN IF @type=1 THEN t.colB=1 END
```

but I get

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
```

and

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
```

What am I doing wrong? It is even possible to do this as a SQL command?

Comment: Use `OR`: `select * from table t where (@type = 0 and t.colA = 1) or (@type = 1 and t.colB = 1) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
select * from table t
where (CASE @type  WHEN 0 THEN colA
                   WHEN 1 THEN colB
       END) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use boolean expressions:

```
select *
from table t
where (@type = 0 and t.colA = 1) or
      (@type = 1 and t.colB = 1)
```

If you want everything when `@type` is not 0 or 1, then include:

```
select *
from table t
where (@type = 0 and t.colA = 1) or
      (@type = 1 and t.colB = 1) or
      (@type not in (0, 1))  -- adjust if @type could be NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE is the "if" function in TSQL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017